# What's the difference between the property "ID" and "BehaviorID" in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, properties

Both seems to have the same functionality. What's the main difference, anyway?

Comment: Functionality? You mean they both contain the same information? And property of what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID is the unique server side identifier of your ASP.NET control.  The behaviorID is an optional client side javascript identifier that can be specified on Extender controls.  They are completely different.